# Is there a tool that can be used with RSpec (or Cucumber) for taking the screenshot of an element of a web page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, cucumber

I am looking for a way to save a screenshot of an element of a web page when I run acceptance tests. Is this possible with Capybara or another tool with RSpec/Cucumber tests?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at phantomjs.

and this question with how to grab only part of the screen.

[How to render part of a page with PhantomJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11917042/how-to-render-part-of-a-page-with-phantomjs)

Comment: Thanks for the link, but one problem with PhantomJS is that it might not be as up-to-date as the Chrome version I am testing against. Also I ideally want to capture screen shots in multiple browsers: Firefox, Chrome, and Safari. In the future I might add IE 10 and Opera to the list too.

Answer (score 0):

Taking a screen shot is very easy with Capybara.

http://www.opinionatedprogrammer.com/2012/01/screenshots-with-capybara-selenium/

However I don't believe there is any current implementation of screenshots that can cherry pick a certain element on the page.