# How to render an html element using phantomjs

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I want to save the image inside the div specified in the code. But using the code below i"m getting some other portion rendered. Is this the correct way to do it? I'm just a beginner in phantomjs. So Please help.

```
var page = require('webpage').create();

page.open("http://n1k0.github.io/casperjs/#phantom_Casper_captureSelector", function    (status) {
    if (status !== 'success') {
        console.log('Unable to load the address!');
    } else {

        var clipRect = page.evaluate(function () { 
        return document.querySelector(".span7 demo").getBoundingClientRect(); });
        page.clipRect = {
            top:    clipRect.top,
            left:   clipRect.left,
            width:  clipRect.width,
            height: clipRect.height
        };



        window.setTimeout(function () {
            page.render('capture.png');
            phantom.exit();
        }, 200);
    }
});
```

Comment: It looks lite it, a quick search gives you this SO thread:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11917042/how-to-render-part-of-a-page-with-phantomjs

Comment: @DanielFigueroa Thanks for the link. Still i'm not able to find the error in my code.

Comment: actually i'm getting a portion rendered. But cropped from some other portion of the same page.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This might be completely wrong but the link that I provided in my comment does it like this:

Change

```
var clipRect = page.evaluate(function () { 
return document.querySelector(".span7 demo").getBoundingClientRect(); });
```

to:

```
var clipRect = document.querySelector(".span7 demo").getBoundingClientRect(); });
```

#### EDIT

Okay so I wanted to figure this one out and here's the code that works for me. I'm not familiar with the phantomjs api to use **querySelector** so I ended up using `getElementsByClassName` which is pretty much the same.

```
var page = require('webpage').create();

page.open("http://n1k0.github.io/casperjs/#phantom_Casper_captureSelector", function    (status) {
    if (status !== 'success') {
        console.log('Unable to load the address!');
    } else {
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            //Heres the actual difference from your code...
            var bb = page.evaluate(function () { 
                return document.getElementsByClassName("span7 demo")[0].getBoundingClientRect(); 
            });

            page.clipRect = {
                top:    bb.top,
                left:   bb.left,
                width:  bb.width,
                height: bb.height
            };

            page.render('capture.png');
            phantom.exit();
        }, 200);
    }
});
```

Comment: It is showing an error now. TypeError: 'null' is not an object <evaluating 'document.queryselector<".span7 demo">.getBountingClientRect'>

Comment: Using var clipRect = page.evaluate(function () { 
return document.querySelector(".span7 demo").getBoundingClientRect(); }); i'm getting the png output. But I'm not getting the div i want.

Comment: Yeah, my answer before was just crap, I'm sorry for that. But I've provided you with an example that works for me now.

Comment: I reused the code and i was trying this on www.google.com trying to extract div lga. It wouldnt work. Any thoughts ?

Answer (score 1):

You can easily capture an element with an ID too. Just replace `getElementsByClassName("classname")[0]` by `document.getElementById('divID')`. A full working example would be:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();

page.open("https://www.sejlar.com/maps.html", function (status) {
    if (status !== 'success') {
        console.log('Page not found');
    } 
    else {
        var p = page.evaluate(function () {
            return document.getElementById('map').getBoundingClientRect();
        });

        page.clipRect = {
            top:    p.top,
            left:   p.left,
            width:  p.width,
            height: p.height
        };

        page.render('screenshot.png');
        phantom.exit(); 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you should do here is surround your return-object with JSON.stringify.

```
return JSON.stringify(document.getElementsByClassName("span7 demo")[0].getBoundingClientRect();
```

or getting the contents of the div

```
return JSON.stringify(document.getElementsByClassName("span7 demo")[0].innerHTML);
```