# How to get all the elements' coordinates

Tags: javascript, dom

If I have know a id of element is "footer" ，I can use

```
 document.getElementById("footer").getBoundingClientRect();
```

to get the "footer" element coordinates.

There is all the code

```
var page = require('webpage').create();

page.open("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18657615/how-to-render-an-html-element-using-phantomjs", function    (status) {
    if (status !== 'success') {
        console.log('Unable to load the address!');
    } else {
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            //Heres the actual difference from your code...
            var bb = page.evaluate(function () {
                //return document.body.getBoundingClientRect();
                return document.getElementById("footer").getBoundingClientRect();    
            });

            page.clipRect = {
                top:    bb.top,
                left:   bb.left,
                width:  bb.width,
                height: bb.height
            };
           console.log(bb.top);
           console.log(bb.left);
           console.log(bb.width);
           console.log(bb.height);

            page.render('capture.png');
            phantom.exit();
        }, 200);
    }
});
```

the result is

4004.6875
0
1075
632.5

I  must know the [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18657615/how-to-render-an-html-element-using-phantomjs) have element that id is "footer".
if there is a unknown webpage, I do not know any info of the webpage.
How I can get all the element coordinates.

Maybe [traversing the dom](https://www.kirupa.com/html5/traversing_the_dom.htm) can help, but I always get errors. I do not know how to merge the code correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's see how we can change the code given in the [link](https://www.kirupa.com/html5/traversing_the_dom.htm) you've found:

> ```
> function theDOMElementWalker(node) {
>     if (node.nodeType == 1) {
>
>         //console.log(node.tagName);
>
>         node = node.firstChild;
>
>         while (node) {
>             theDOMElementWalker(node);
>             node = node.nextSibling;
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

This can be easily extended to "copy" the DOM to a custom representation. For example:

```
var dom = page.evaluate(function(){
    var root = { children: [] };
    function walk(node, obj) {
        if (node.nodeType == 1) {

            obj.tagName = node.tagName;
            obj.boundingClientRect = node.getBoundingClientRect();

            node = node.firstChild;

            var childObj;
            while (node) {
                childObj = { children: [] };
                obj.children.push(childObj);
                walk(node, childObj);
                node = node.nextSibling;
            }
        }
    }

    walk(document.documentElement, root);

    return root;
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(dom, undefined, 4));
```

The idea here is to pass in the DOM node and its "simple" representation into the walk function.

Comment: You are so nice. Thank you very much!