# generate screenshot of a specific DOM element with phantom.js

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I use phantom.js and the follwing snippet to generate an automatic screenshot of a website. Is it possible to screenshot only the content of a specific DOM element? According to my example i want only an image with the content of div class="sfibbbc" (div element on google.com)

**Call:**

phantomjs rasterize.js http://www.google.com myimage.png 1400px*900px

**Code:**

```
"use strict";
var page = require('webpage').create(),
system = require('system'),
address, output, size, pageWidth, pageHeight;

if (system.args.length < 3 || system.args.length > 5) {
    console.log('Usage: rasterize.js URL filename [paperwidth*paperheight|paperformat] [zoom]');
    console.log('  paper (pdf output) examples: "5in*7.5in", "10cm*20cm", "A4", "Letter"');
    console.log('  image (png/jpg output) examples: "1920px" entire page, window width 1920px');
    console.log('                                   "800px*600px" window, clipped to 800x600');
    phantom.exit(1);
} else {
    address = system.args[1];
    output = system.args[2];
    page.viewportSize = { width: 600, height: 600 };
    if (system.args.length > 3 && system.args[2].substr(-4) === ".pdf") {
        size = system.args[3].split('*');
        page.paperSize = size.length === 2 ? { width: size[0], height: size[1], margin: '0px' }
        : { format: system.args[3], orientation: 'portrait', margin: '1cm' };
    } else if (system.args.length > 3 && system.args[3].substr(-2) === "px") {
        size = system.args[3].split('*');
        if (size.length === 2) {
            pageWidth = parseInt(size[0], 10);
            pageHeight = parseInt(size[1], 10);
            page.viewportSize = { width: pageWidth, height: pageHeight };
            page.clipRect = { top: 0, left: 0, width: pageWidth, height: pageHeight };
        } else {
            console.log("size:", system.args[3]);
            pageWidth = parseInt(system.args[3], 10);
pageHeight = parseInt(pageWidth * 3/4, 10); // it's as good an assumption as any
console.log ("pageHeight:",pageHeight);
page.viewportSize = { width: pageWidth, height: pageHeight };
}
}
if (system.args.length > 4) {
    page.zoomFactor = system.args[4];
}
page.open(address, function (status) {
    if (status !== 'success') {
        console.log('Unable to load the address!');
        phantom.exit(1);
    } else {
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            page.render(output);
            phantom.exit();
        }, 200);
    }
});
}
```

Comment: here's a working example:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11917042/how-to-render-part-of-a-page-with-phantomjs