# how to screenshot a div using phantomJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, phantomjs, screenshot

Hi does anyone here can help me to screenshot my div using phantomJS?
How can i Screenshot my `#dropzone` then append it on the same page?

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can partially render a webpage.

1) Make an extra page with just the div, screenshot it using render, and use the result on your actual page.

2) Use the clipRect functionality (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11917042/how-to-render-part-of-a-page-with-phantomjs)):

```
var clipRect = document.querySelector(selector).getBoundingClientRect();
page.clipRect = {
    top:    clipRect.top,
    left:   clipRect.left,
    width:  clipRect.width,
    height: clipRect.height
};
page.render('capture.png');
```

Comment: Hello can you describe how we can make "an extra page" with just the div ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use [node-webshot](https://github.com/brenden/node-webshot) to do so,
take a look at [options](https://github.com/brenden/node-webshot#options) then the `captureSelector` option.