# Phantom JS and Component

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, phantomjs

I gave a read to the phantomjs docs and I came to know that it will capture entire page for the given link. And read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11917042/how-to-render-part-of-a-page-with-phantomjs) in this site tells me that a part of page has to be clipped for custom page view. But I am wondering if I use phantomjs for react application where I want to get entire component which is part of some page and some fixed size. Can I get that image? And If not what could be the possible cases which I can use for doing so?