# How to hide all but one child(grandchild) of element in dom

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a container for all my elements and I hide all of its children like so :

```
$("#svgContainer").children().hide();
```

I have two elements that are the 'SVGContainer''s grandchildren :

`#canvasParent` & `#canvasChild`.

I have tried doing this :

```
$("#svgContainer").children().hide();
        $("#canvasParent").show();
        $("#canvasChild").show();
```

This doesn't seem to work, probably because the `display:none;` gets given to the parent not the child.

How do I go about hiding every one of the SVGContainers children except for the elements with id's : `#canvasParent` & `#canvasChild`.

Here's a fiddle of the layout I have : http://jsfiddle.net/o9zowx3b/1/

Notice it hides all elements still, I think this is due to them being grandchildren not children of the svgContainer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also do it with single selector:

```js
$("#svgContainer > :not(#canvasParent,#canvasChild)").hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="svgContainer">
    <div id="canvasParent">canvasParent</div>
    <div>should be hidden</div>
    <div id="canvasChild">canvasChild</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have mentioned this in another comment but not in the question.Both canvasParent & canvasChild are granchildren of the svgContainer. So none of these methods are working. I've updated a fiddle @LaVomit created. http://jsfiddle.net/o9zowx3b/1/ in this it has the same layout as my problem. Appreciate it if you can take a look :)

Comment: Then selector will be like this: `$("#svgContainer > #svg > :not(#canvasParent,#canvasChild,#showMe)").hide();`. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/o9zowx3b/2/

Answer (score 2):

What you're wanting to do is hide all of the siblings of a particular element. That's relatively simple with jQuery using the  [.siblings](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) method:

```
$("#svgContainer").children().hide();​​​​
```

This will hide all elements on the same level, in the same parent element.

Comment: this is amazing, i shall check it works now :) thanks

Comment: it"s ok sir @thisOneGuy

Comment: am i able to select multiple elements to keep in view ? Like $("#canvasParent, #canvasChild").siblings().hide();​​​​ doesnt seem to work :/

Comment: See this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535331/how-to-hide-all-elements-except-one-using-jquery

Comment: This answer is wrong. It's about the children of the selected element, not the siblings.

Comment: ya wait sir i check it

Answer (score 2):

This should work as requested.

```
$('#svgContainer').children().not('#canvasParent').not('#canvasChild').hide();
```

[Here is a fiddle, specially for you!](http://jsfiddle.net/o9zowx3b/)

Good luck.

Comment: you are amazing haha this works great. However, ive forgot to mention the way mine is set out. The canvasParent&canvasChild are grandchildren not children of the svgContainer. Are you able to amend this updated fiddle ? http://jsfiddle.net/o9zowx3b/1/ You can see it hides everything :(

Answer (score 1):

This will select all children except the 2 children.

```
$("#svgContainer").children().not("#canvasParent,#canvasChild").hide();
```